# How do I use a 3rd party C library in Xcode for my iphone project?

Tags: iphone, c, xcode, linker

love this site and all helpful people! I'm newbie to Xcode and iPhone programming but I've pretty much got the hang of using the SDK to make programs in Obj-C (simple programs right now but make me happy). My experience is web programming (such as PHP and Perl) and I'm not really used to a lot of the new Xcode/desktopy-app stuff like static libraries and linking and such. I be honest, I am not total awesome programmer yet!

I have a problem right now, my (card game) program I am writing needs to use [this](http://www.codingthewheel.com/archives/a-pokersource-poker-eval-primer) C library. I don't really understand how I get the proper C files and integrate them into my project so I can start using the commands in that tutorial to evaluate hand values.

I hope I have been clear, please let me know if there is anything I am leaving out. Unfortunately, my newbieness may prevent from me making everything so clear and sometimes I can't english perfectly what I am thinking!

Happy thanks in advance, looking forward to any help!

Answer (score 1):

Couple things:

- The library you linked to is quite large. Pokersource appears to be a large C project containing all sorts of things like language bindings and some GUI tools as well. A project that large certainly has an IRC channel. I would recommend going there.
- The library you linked to appears to be (I may be wrong about this), licensed under the GPLv3. This means that any program that you distribute to others that uses a GPLv3 library or piece of code must also be licensed under the GPLv3. The upshot is that if you use that library, you'll have to release the source for your game.

The site you linked to does [seem to have a long list of other poker hand evaluators](http://www.codingthewheel.com/archives/poker-hand-evaluator-roundup), so its possible one of them is suitable for your needs.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

it's totally possible to use third party static libraries with your iPhone and using Xcode. [This](http://blog.stormyprods.com/2008/11/using-static-libraries-with-iphone-sdk.html) webpage illustrates the process of doing it.